# Incorrect date format from Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData provider to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, odata, date-format

I am using [Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData](https://github.com/OData/AspNetCoreOData).

For the url filter

```
?$count=true&$top=100&$filter=Date%20gt%202022-03-17T00:00:00.000Z
```

the OData provider output to SQL Server is

```
AND ([q].[Date] > ''2022-03-17T00:00:00.000000'')
```

are this is not supported in SQL Server.

I get this error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Dropping the last 3 zeroes makes it work in SQL Server.

Is there an OData config for date formatting?

Comment: What data type is `q.date`? Presumably it's a `datetime`? If so, your value (`2022-03-17T00:00:00.000000`) has too a too high a precision; `datetime` only supports an accuracy of up to 1/300 of a second. `2022-03-17T00:00:00.000000` would, however, be supported by the "new" data and time data types.

Comment: both types (on MSSQL and ASP model) are `datetime`
 Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData default convert is to 6 `.000000` (from `000z`)

Comment: Dates don't have formats, they are binary values. Date *literals* do have formats, some of which are ambiguous. Please tell me you are not injecting literals of data into your SQL query?? Why not pass through a proper `datetime` parameter: `AND ([q].[Date] > @date)` would never fail.

Comment: i am using  Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData as proxy
i send  url, and  Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData send the sql to server

Comment: `'2022-03-17T00:00:00.000000'` isn't a `datetime`, @mordechai , it's a `varchar`; as as you've found out, it's not a valid value that can in (implicitly) converted to a `datetime` either. Again, that is because the precision of the date and time value the `varchar` represents is too high for a `datetime`.

Comment: but is the output of  Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData...
this the property.
public DateTime Date { get; set; }
and all other is Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData output,

Comment: `202022-03-17T00:00:00.000Z` is also string? is it not an odata standard?

Comment: I don't see how OData has anything to do with a query you send to SQL Server

Comment: @mordechai `DateTime` has no format either in .NET or SQL Server. Both are binary values. You didn't post *any* code that connect the OData call to a database call. If you used EF Core, the generated SQL query wouldn't use date strings, it would use a parameterized query with strongly typed DateTime parameters. This means the problem is caused by *your* code. Post your code

Comment: @mordechai `the OData provider output to SQL Server` what does that mean? OData is a protocol, it has no providers. Neither does `Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData`. You'd have to create a Controller to handle each entity and possibly connect it to EF Core

Comment: here is my content of the odata conteroller:

        `[EnableQuery]

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            return Ok( this._context.VoucherActivities
                .Where(e=>e.Status != Model.VouchersStatus.NotInitialize)
                .AsQueryable());
        }`

  sql describe is from the profiler.

Comment: I don't see a date in that code, please show all relevant code, and please paste it into your question as an [edit], not in a comment

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in EF configuration, if you use Fluent API you should add:

```
entity.Property(e => e.Date)
    .HasColumnType("datetime")
```

to entity configuration in the DbContext.
Or else:

```
[Column(TypeName="datetime")]
```

attribute to the property in the model.